# Keypad code not working

Tags: keypad

I am new I took a code of keypad in arduino. Arduino code is not working in setup area but if I place the same code in loop are it works why? Kindly guide me.
Here is the code.

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'0','1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6','7'},
  {'8','9','A','B'},
  {'C','D','E','F'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4,5}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

  if (customKey){
    Serial.println(customKey);
  }
}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: Please note that `setup()` runs just once while `loop()` is repeated forever (see e.g. [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18864/17196)) that's an important difference.

Comment: but it must run once, it is not .

Comment: It is. It's just running waaaaay faster than you can press a key.

Comment: I think you need to learn the difference between "Running once right at the very start" and "Getting one keypress". The two concepts are completely different.

Comment: Ok thanks alot.

Comment: To illustrate what the are talking about, try putting an else on your if.... I.e. ```else { Serial.println("no key press"); } ```. As a bonus you will get a free game called "can I beat the no key press message?" :-)